# errors when installing mmcv

Tags: python, pytorch

When I tried to install mmcv, I just ran `pip install mmcv-full==1.1.5 -f https://download.openmmlab.com/mmcv/dist/cu110/torch1.7.0/index.html`
but it errors:

```
    Running setup.py install for mmcv-full ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /root/miniconda3/bin/python -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-oj43u6y1/mmcv-full_309ced516e854af491f11139bb042f90/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-oj43u6y1/mmcv-full_309ced516e854af491f11139bb042f90/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-jgjp5eph/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /root/miniconda3/include/python3.8/mmcv-full
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-oj43u6y1/mmcv-full_309ced516e854af491f11139bb042f90/
    Complete output (424 lines):
    No CUDA runtime is found, using CUDA_HOME='/usr/local/cuda'
    Compiling mmcv._ext without CUDA
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/mmcv
    ...(many copying...)

    running egg_info
    writing mmcv_full.egg-info/PKG-INFO
    writing dependency_links to mmcv_full.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
    writing requirements to mmcv_full.egg-info/requires.txt
    writing top-level names to mmcv_full.egg-info/top_level.txt
    reading manifest file 'mmcv_full.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
    writing manifest file 'mmcv_full.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/mmcv/model_zoo
    copying mmcv/model_zoo/deprecated.json -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/mmcv/model_zoo
    copying mmcv/model_zoo/mmcls.json -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/mmcv/model_zoo
    copying mmcv/model_zoo/open_mmlab.json -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/mmcv/model_zoo
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/mmcv/ops/csrc
    ...(many copying...)
    running build_ext
    building 'mmcv._flow_warp_ext' extension
    creating /tmp/pip-install-oj43u6y1/mmcv-full_309ced516e854af491f11139bb042f90/build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8
    creating /tmp/pip-install-oj43u6y1/mmcv-full_309ced516e854af491f11139bb042f90/build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/mmcv
    creating /tmp/pip-install-oj43u6y1/mmcv-full_309ced516e854af491f11139bb042f90/build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/mmcv/video
    creating /tmp/pip-install-oj43u6y1/mmcv-full_309ced516e854af491f11139bb042f90/build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/mmcv/video/optflow_warp
    Emitting ninja build file /tmp/pip-install-oj43u6y1/mmcv-full_309ced516e854af491f11139bb042f90/build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/build.ninja...
    Compiling objects...
    Using envvar MAX_JOBS (4) as the number of workers...
    [1/2] c++ -MMD -MF /tmp/pip-install-oj43u6y1/mmcv-full_309ced516e854af491f11139bb042f90/build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/mmcv/video/optflow_warp/flow_warp.o.d -pthread -B /root/miniconda3/compiler_compat -Wl,--sysroot=/ -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I./mmcv/video/optflow_warp -I/root/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/root/miniconda3/include/python3.8 -c -c /tmp/pip-install-oj43u6y1/mmcv-full_309ced516e854af491f11139bb042f90/mmcv/video/optflow_warp/flow_warp.cpp -o /tmp/pip-install-oj43u6y1/mmcv-full_309ced516e854af491f11139bb042f90/build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/mmcv/video/optflow_warp/flow_warp.o -DTORCH_API_INCLUDE_EXTENSION_H -DTORCH_EXTENSION_NAME=_flow_warp_ext -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0 -std=c++14
    cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wstrict-prototypes’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
    [2/2] c++ -MMD -MF /tmp/pip-install-oj43u6y1/mmcv-full_309ced516e854af491f11139bb042f90/build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/mmcv/video/optflow_warp/flow_warp_module.o.d -pthread -B /root/miniconda3/compiler_compat -Wl,--sysroot=/ -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I./mmcv/video/optflow_warp -I/root/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/root/miniconda3/include/python3.8 -c -c /tmp/pip-install-oj43u6y1/mmcv-full_309ced516e854af491f11139bb042f90/mmcv/video/optflow_warp/flow_warp_module.cpp -o /tmp/pip-install-oj43u6y1/mmcv-full_309ced516e854af491f11139bb042f90/build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/mmcv/video/optflow_warp/flow_warp_module.o -DTORCH_API_INCLUDE_EXTENSION_H -DTORCH_EXTENSION_NAME=_flow_warp_ext -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0 -std=c++14
    cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wstrict-prototypes’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
    In file included from /root/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarraytypes.h:1969:0,
                     from /root/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarrayobject.h:12,
                     from /root/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/arrayobject.h:4,
                     from /tmp/pip-install-oj43u6y1/mmcv-full_309ced516e854af491f11139bb042f90/mmcv/video/optflow_warp/flow_warp_module.cpp:786:
    /root/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/npy_1_7_deprecated_api.h:17:2: warning: #warning "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it with " "#define NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION" [-Wcpp]
     #warning "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it with " \
      ^~~~~~~
    g++ -pthread -shared -B /root/miniconda3/compiler_compat -L/root/miniconda3/lib -Wl,-rpath=/root/miniconda3/lib -Wl,--no-as-needed -Wl,--sysroot=/ /tmp/pip-install-oj43u6y1/mmcv-full_309ced516e854af491f11139bb042f90/build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/./mmcv/video/optflow_warp/flow_warp_module.o /tmp/pip-install-oj43u6y1/mmcv-full_309ced516e854af491f11139bb042f90/build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/./mmcv/video/optflow_warp/flow_warp.o -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/mmcv/_flow_warp_ext.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
    building 'mmcv._ext' extension
    creating /tmp/pip-install-oj43u6y1/mmcv-full_309ced516e854af491f11139bb042f90/build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/mmcv/ops
    creating /tmp/pip-install-oj43u6y1/mmcv-full_309ced516e854af491f11139bb042f90/build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/mmcv/ops/csrc
    creating /tmp/pip-install-oj43u6y1/mmcv-full_309ced516e854af491f11139bb042f90/build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/mmcv/ops/csrc/pytorch
    Emitting ninja build file /tmp/pip-install-oj43u6y1/mmcv-full_309ced516e854af491f11139bb042f90/build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/build.ninja...
    Compiling objects...
    Using envvar MAX_JOBS (4) as the number of workers...
    [1/19] c++ -MMD -MF /tmp/pip-install-oj43u6y1/mmcv-full_309ced516e854af491f11139bb042f90/build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/mmcv/ops/csrc/pytorch/carafe.o.d -pthread -B /root/miniconda3/compiler_compat -Wl,--sysroot=/ -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/tmp/pip-install-oj43u6y1/mmcv-full_309ced516e854af491f11139bb042f90/mmcv/ops/csrc -I/root/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/include -I/root/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/include/torch/csrc/api/include -I/root/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/include/TH -I/root/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/include/THC -I/root/miniconda3/include/python3.8 -c -c /tmp/pip-install-oj43u6y1/mmcv-full_309ced516e854af491f11139bb042f90/mmcv/ops/csrc/pytorch/carafe.cpp -o /tmp/pip-install-oj43u6y1/mmcv-full_309ced516e854af491f11139bb042f90/build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/mmcv/ops/csrc/pytorch/carafe.o -DTORCH_API_INCLUDE_EXTENSION_H -DTORCH_EXTENSION_NAME=_ext -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0 -std=c++14
    FAILED: /tmp/pip-install-oj43u6y1/mmcv-full_309ced516e854af491f11139bb042f90/build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/mmcv/ops/csrc/pytorch/carafe.o
    c++ -MMD -MF /tmp/pip-install-oj43u6y1/mmcv-full_309ced516e854af491f11139bb042f90/build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/mmcv/ops/csrc/pytorch/carafe.o.d -pthread -B /root/miniconda3/compiler_compat -Wl,--sysroot=/ -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/tmp/pip-install-oj43u6y1/mmcv-full_309ced516e854af491f11139bb042f90/mmcv/ops/csrc -I/root/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/include -I/root/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/include/torch/csrc/api/include -I/root/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/include/TH -I/root/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/include/THC -I/root/miniconda3/include/python3.8 -c -c /tmp/pip-install-oj43u6y1/mmcv-full_309ced516e854af491f11139bb042f90/mmcv/ops/csrc/pytorch/carafe.cpp -o /tmp/pip-install-oj43u6y1/mmcv-full_309ced516e854af491f11139bb042f90/build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/mmcv/ops/csrc/pytorch/carafe.o -DTORCH_API_INCLUDE_EXTENSION_H -DTORCH_EXTENSION_NAME=_ext -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0 -std=c++14
    cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wstrict-prototypes’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
    In file included from /root/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/include/ATen/Parallel.h:149:0,
                     from /root/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/include/torch/csrc/api/include/torch/utils.h:3,
                     from /root/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/include/torch/csrc/api/include/torch/nn/cloneable.h:5,
                     from /root/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/include/torch/csrc/api/include/torch/nn.h:3,
                     from /root/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/include/torch/csrc/api/include/torch/all.h:12,
                     from /root/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/include/torch/extension.h:4,
                     from /tmp/pip-install-oj43u6y1/mmcv-full_309ced516e854af491f11139bb042f90/mmcv/ops/csrc/pytorch_cpp_helper.hpp:3,
                     from /tmp/pip-install-oj43u6y1/mmcv-full_309ced516e854af491f11139bb042f90/mmcv/ops/csrc/pytorch/carafe.cpp:1:
    /root/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/include/ATen/ParallelOpenMP.h:84:0: warning: ignoring #pragma omp parallel [-Wunknown-pragmas]
     #pragma omp parallel for if ((end - begin) >= grain_size)
    
    c++: internal compiler error: Killed (program cc1plus)
    Please submit a full bug report,
    with preprocessed source if appropriate.
    See <file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-7/README.Bugs> for instructions.
    [2/19] c++ -MMD -MF /tmp/pip-install-oj43u6y1/mmcv-full_309ced516e854af491f11139bb042f90/build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/mmcv/ops/csrc/pytorch/cc_attention.o.d -pthread -B /root/miniconda3/compiler_compat -Wl,--sysroot=/ -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/tmp/pip-install-oj43u6y1/mmcv-full_309ced516e854af491f11139bb042f90/mmcv/ops/csrc -I/root/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/include -I/root/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/include/torch/csrc/api/include -I/root/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/include/TH -I/root/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/include/THC -I/root/miniconda3/include/python3.8 -c -c /tmp/pip-install-oj43u6y1/mmcv-full_309ced516e854af491f11139bb042f90/mmcv/ops/csrc/pytorch/cc_attention.cpp -o /tmp/pip-install-oj43u6y1/mmcv-full_309ced516e854af491f11139bb042f90/build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/mmcv/ops/csrc/pytorch/cc_attention.o -DTORCH_API_INCLUDE_EXTENSION_H -DTORCH_EXTENSION_NAME=_ext -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0 -std=c++14
    FAILED: /tmp/pip-install-oj43u6y1/mmcv-full_309ced516e854af491f11139bb042f90/build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/mmcv/ops/csrc/pytorch/cc_attention.o
    c++ -MMD -MF /tmp/pip-install-oj43u6y1/mmcv-full_309ced516e854af491f11139bb042f90/build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/mmcv/ops/csrc/pytorch/cc_attention.o.d -pthread -B /root/miniconda3/compiler_compat -Wl,--sysroot=/ -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/tmp/pip-install-oj43u6y1/mmcv-full_309ced516e854af491f11139bb042f90/mmcv/ops/csrc -I/root/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/include -I/root/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/include/torch/csrc/api/include -I/root/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/include/TH -I/root/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/include/THC -I/root/miniconda3/include/python3.8 -c -c /tmp/pip-install-oj43u6y1/mmcv-full_309ced516e854af491f11139bb042f90/mmcv/ops/csrc/pytorch/cc_attention.cpp -o /tmp/pip-install-oj43u6y1/mmcv-full_309ced516e854af491f11139bb042f90/build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/mmcv/ops/csrc/pytorch/cc_attention.o -DTORCH_API_INCLUDE_EXTENSION_H -DTORCH_EXTENSION_NAME=_ext -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0 -std=c++14
    cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wstrict-prototypes’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
    In file included from /root/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/include/ATen/Parallel.h:149:0,
                     from /root/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/include/torch/csrc/api/include/torch/utils.h:3,
                     from /root/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/include/torch/csrc/api/include/torch/nn/cloneable.h:5,
                     from /root/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/include/torch/csrc/api/include/torch/nn.h:3,
                     from /root/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/include/torch/csrc/api/include/torch/all.h:12,
                     from /root/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/include/torch/extension.h:4,
                     from /tmp/pip-install-oj43u6y1/mmcv-full_309ced516e854af491f11139bb042f90/mmcv/ops/csrc/pytorch_cpp_helper.hpp:3,
                     from /tmp/pip-install-oj43u6y1/mmcv-full_309ced516e854af491f11139bb042f90/mmcv/ops/csrc/pytorch/cc_attention.cpp:1:
    /root/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/include/ATen/ParallelOpenMP.h:84:0: warning: ignoring #pragma omp parallel [-Wunknown-pragmas]
     #pragma omp parallel for if ((end - begin) >= grain_size)
    
    c++: internal compiler error: Killed (program cc1plus)
    Please submit a full bug report,
    with preprocessed source if appropriate.
    See <file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-7/README.Bugs> for instructions.
    [3/19] c++ -MMD -MF /tmp/pip-install-oj43u6y1/mmcv-full_309ced516e854af491f11139bb042f90/build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/mmcv/ops/csrc/pytorch/bbox_overlaps.o.d -pthread -B /root/miniconda3/compiler_compat -Wl,--sysroot=/ -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/tmp/pip-install-oj43u6y1/mmcv-full_309ced516e854af491f11139bb042f90/mmcv/ops/csrc -I/root/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/include -I/root/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/include/torch/csrc/api/include -I/root/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/include/TH -I/root/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/include/THC -I/root/miniconda3/include/python3.8 -c -c /tmp/pip-install-oj43u6y1/mmcv-full_309ced516e854af491f11139bb042f90/mmcv/ops/csrc/pytorch/bbox_overlaps.cpp -o /tmp/pip-install-oj43u6y1/mmcv-full_309ced516e854af491f11139bb042f90/build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/mmcv/ops/csrc/pytorch/bbox_overlaps.o -DTORCH_API_INCLUDE_EXTENSION_H -DTORCH_EXTENSION_NAME=_ext -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0 -std=c++14
    FAILED: /tmp/pip-install-oj43u6y1/mmcv-full_309ced516e854af491f11139bb042f90/build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/mmcv/ops/csrc/pytorch/bbox_overlaps.o
    c++ -MMD -MF /tmp/pip-install-oj43u6y1/mmcv-full_309ced516e854af491f11139bb042f90/build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/mmcv/ops/csrc/pytorch/bbox_overlaps.o.d -pthread -B /root/miniconda3/compiler_compat -Wl,--sysroot=/ -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/tmp/pip-install-oj43u6y1/mmcv-full_309ced516e854af491f11139bb042f90/mmcv/ops/csrc -I/root/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/include -I/root/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/include/torch/csrc/api/include -I/root/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/include/TH -I/root/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/include/THC -I/root/miniconda3/include/python3.8 -c -c /tmp/pip-install-oj43u6y1/mmcv-full_309ced516e854af491f11139bb042f90/mmcv/ops/csrc/pytorch/bbox_overlaps.cpp -o /tmp/pip-install-oj43u6y1/mmcv-full_309ced516e854af491f11139bb042f90/build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/mmcv/ops/csrc/pytorch/bbox_overlaps.o -DTORCH_API_INCLUDE_EXTENSION_H -DTORCH_EXTENSION_NAME=_ext -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0 -std=c++14
    cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wstrict-prototypes’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
    In file included from /root/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/include/ATen/Parallel.h:149:0,
                     from /root/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/include/torch/csrc/api/include/torch/utils.h:3,
                     from /root/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/include/torch/csrc/api/include/torch/nn/cloneable.h:5,
                     from /root/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/include/torch/csrc/api/include/torch/nn.h:3,
                     from /root/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/include/torch/csrc/api/include/torch/all.h:12,
                     from /root/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/include/torch/extension.h:4,
                     from /tmp/pip-install-oj43u6y1/mmcv-full_309ced516e854af491f11139bb042f90/mmcv/ops/csrc/pytorch_cpp_helper.hpp:3,
                     from /tmp/pip-install-oj43u6y1/mmcv-full_309ced516e854af491f11139bb042f90/mmcv/ops/csrc/pytorch/bbox_overlaps.cpp:1:
    /root/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/include/ATen/ParallelOpenMP.h:84:0: warning: ignoring #pragma omp parallel [-Wunknown-pragmas]
     #pragma omp parallel for if ((end - begin) >= grain_size)
    
    c++: internal compiler error: Killed (program cc1plus)
    Please submit a full bug report,
    with preprocessed source if appropriate.
    See <file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-7/README.Bugs> for instructions.
    [4/19] c++ -MMD -MF /tmp/pip-install-oj43u6y1/mmcv-full_309ced516e854af491f11139bb042f90/build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/mmcv/ops/csrc/pytorch/carafe_naive.o.d -pthread -B /root/miniconda3/compiler_compat -Wl,--sysroot=/ -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/tmp/pip-install-oj43u6y1/mmcv-full_309ced516e854af491f11139bb042f90/mmcv/ops/csrc -I/root/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/include -I/root/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/include/torch/csrc/api/include -I/root/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/include/TH -I/root/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/include/THC -I/root/miniconda3/include/python3.8 -c -c /tmp/pip-install-oj43u6y1/mmcv-full_309ced516e854af491f11139bb042f90/mmcv/ops/csrc/pytorch/carafe_naive.cpp -o /tmp/pip-install-oj43u6y1/mmcv-full_309ced516e854af491f11139bb042f90/build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/mmcv/ops/csrc/pytorch/carafe_naive.o -DTORCH_API_INCLUDE_EXTENSION_H -DTORCH_EXTENSION_NAME=_ext -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0 -std=c++14
    cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wstrict-prototypes’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
    In file included from /root/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/include/ATen/Parallel.h:149:0,
                     from /root/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/include/torch/csrc/api/include/torch/utils.h:3,
                     from /root/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/include/torch/csrc/api/include/torch/nn/cloneable.h:5,
                     from /root/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/include/torch/csrc/api/include/torch/nn.h:3,
                     from /root/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/include/torch/csrc/api/include/torch/all.h:12,
                     from /root/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/include/torch/extension.h:4,
                     from /tmp/pip-install-oj43u6y1/mmcv-full_309ced516e854af491f11139bb042f90/mmcv/ops/csrc/pytorch_cpp_helper.hpp:3,
                     from /tmp/pip-install-oj43u6y1/mmcv-full_309ced516e854af491f11139bb042f90/mmcv/ops/csrc/pytorch/carafe_naive.cpp:1:
    /root/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/include/ATen/ParallelOpenMP.h:84:0: warning: ignoring #pragma omp parallel [-Wunknown-pragmas]
     #pragma omp parallel for if ((end - begin) >= grain_size)
    
    ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/root/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/utils/cpp_extension.py", line 1516, in _run_ninja_build
        subprocess.run(
      File "/root/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 516, in run
        raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args,
    subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['ninja', '-v', '-j', '4']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
    
    The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
    
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-install-oj43u6y1/mmcv-full_309ced516e854af491f11139bb042f90/setup.py", line 194, in <module>
        setup(
      File "/root/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 153, in setup
        return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
      File "/root/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "/root/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/distutils/dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "/root/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/root/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/command/install.py", line 61, in run
        return orig.install.run(self)
      File "/root/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/distutils/command/install.py", line 545, in run
        self.run_command('build')
      File "/root/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "/root/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/root/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/distutils/command/build.py", line 135, in run
        self.run_command(cmd_name)
      File "/root/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "/root/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/root/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/command/build_ext.py", line 79, in run
        _build_ext.run(self)
      File "/root/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 340, in run
        self.build_extensions()
      File "/root/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/utils/cpp_extension.py", line 653, in build_extensions
        build_ext.build_extensions(self)
      File "/root/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 449, in build_extensions
        self._build_extensions_serial()
      File "/root/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 474, in _build_extensions_serial
        self.build_extension(ext)
      File "/root/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/command/build_ext.py", line 196, in build_extension
        _build_ext.build_extension(self, ext)
      File "/root/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 528, in build_extension
        objects = self.compiler.compile(sources,
      File "/root/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/utils/cpp_extension.py", line 473, in unix_wrap_ninja_compile
        _write_ninja_file_and_compile_objects(
      File "/root/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/utils/cpp_extension.py", line 1233, in _write_ninja_file_and_compile_objects
        _run_ninja_build(
      File "/root/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/utils/cpp_extension.py", line 1538, in _run_ninja_build
        raise RuntimeError(message) from e
    RuntimeError: Error compiling objects for extension
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /root/miniconda3/bin/python -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-oj43u6y1/mmcv-full_309ced516e854af491f11139bb042f90/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-oj43u6y1/mmcv-full_309ced516e854af491f11139bb042f90/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-jgjp5eph/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /root/miniconda3/include/python3.8/mmcv-full Check the logs for full command output.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try out the below code, It worked for me without any issues.

```
!pip install -U openmim
!mim install mmcv-full
```

If the code fixes the issue, then accept the answer.